# How to sort date data type?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I've been trying to sort dates on A1 but it sorts based on text not the value

```
Private Sub sortData()

Worksheets(Me.Combobox1.Value).Range("A1:F1", Range("A1:F1").End(xlDown)).Sort
 Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: To solve an algorithmic problem, one has to first understand the algorithm.  What sort of algorithm would fulfill your expectations?  Solve it first on a piece of paper; you will then be in a much better position to write code.

Comment: I made a few arrangements. Still doesn't work

Comment: Your so called Dates appear to actually be strings that only look like dates.   These will sort differently to actual dates.  The correct solution is to fix your data, turning it into real dates

Comment: They all are date data type

Comment: No, they don't. If they were actual dates, then your code would work correctly. Click in cell A1, and then look at the value in the expression bar. What does it say there?

Comment: @KenWhite It is obviously General A1 because it is the title. A2 and soo on are Date

Comment: I just copy and paste your 30 cells example and modified "A1:F1" to "A1:C10". It ordered all rows by date correctly.

Comment: I have more data besides just C column but still does not work

Comment: It's perfectly possible to have a text string in a cell formatted as *Date* or *General*. Please do the test @Ken White has suggested: Select any of your dates and format its cell as *Number*. If you see a number it's a true date. If you continue to see the same "date" it's a fake.

Comment: @KenWhite is right; there is no way to sort your text dates as date/time as long as these have not been corrected or converted, neither will the two "answers" below help you.

Comment: It is possible with DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marcelo Scofano Diniz started to say, when you run into a problem forget about the shortcxuts and go by the book. Here is the book.

```
Private Sub SortByDate()
    
    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    Dim SortRange       As Range
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
    With Ws
        Set SortRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                        .Resize(, 6)
        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=SortRange.Cells(1), _
                  SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                  Order:=xlAscending, _
                  DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        
        With .Sort
            .SetRange SortRange
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code will carry out the sort you say your code won't do. If the dates are true dates they will be sorted by date. If they are fake dates they will be sorted as text. And if you have doubt about any part of the code you can see what is being done and step through it line by line.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!  Note: If the dates wouldn't be true date values it could be easily fixed by writing the dataOption as follows: DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

Answer (score 0):

Change The Range to Table of Name Tbl
then Create :

```
Sub Table_Sort(byval FieldNo as Integer)
    Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    FieldRange(FieldNo).Select
       Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add _
   Key:=FieldRange(FieldNo), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
   xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

   With Tbl.Sort

   .Header = xlYes
   .MatchCase = False
   .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
   .SortMethod = xlPinYin
   .Apply
   
   End With

End Sub
```